# iOS table preview image release

Tags: asynchronous, rss, uitableview

I'm testing an RSS on my iPhone. It uses 0 nib files. I'll try to describe it as best as I can, and will post code if its required, but I bet its a common phenomena with a common solution. The issue is in a tableviewcontroller, and the solution probably needs to be implemented in the CellForRowAtIndexPath method. If I scroll down, preview images stay in their respective spots until the async queue loads the correct image for that cell. So if I have an image for array item 1, and I scroll down to array item 20, the image for array item 1 will still be there until my queue catches up and loads that image. How can I release the images from cells that I am not viewing? Thank you for your time.

Here is my CellForRow...

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
ArticleItem *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
cell.primaryLabel.text = object.title;
cell.secondaryLabel.text = object.strippedDescription;
cell.primaryLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.primaryLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.primaryLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.secondaryLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

//Async dispatch queue for image preview loading...
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{ 

    UIImage *preview = nil;
    if (object.iG = nil)
    {
        preview = [UIImage imageNamed:@"CellLogo.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        preview = [UIImage imageWithData:object.iG];
    } 
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [[cell myImageView] setImage:preview];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
return cell;   
}
```

If you gather, I have an ArticleItem class which pulls the image URLS and turns them into data , and I have a CustomCell class which does what its called.
    CustomCell.h
    @interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {
        UIImageView *myImageView;
    }
    @property(nonatomic,strong)UIImageView *myImageView;
    @end
    =====================================================
    CustomCell.m

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
    // Initialization code
            myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];


    [self.contentView addSubview:myImageView];       
}
return self;
}
-(void)viewDidUnload {
myImageView = nil;
primaryLabel = nil;
secondaryLabel = nil;
}
```

Comment: can you show us your codes ?

Comment: Thank you, I have added my CellForRow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a subclass of UITableViewcell, make a property for imageview. As soon as it gets away from visibility, it will be released. Describing just the overview as you may yourself need to see the usage upon scrolling.

Comment: Ok, I have an ArticleItem class which finds and defines the data for the images, and a CustomCell UITableViewCell class for formatting my cells already in place. Should I somehow implement the image data in my already existing UITableViewCell class?

Comment: Visit this tutorial, they have made a custom imageview for the cell: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ - By making thumbnailImageView as strong property (they have made it weak there) - you will ensure that as soon as cell goes out of view it will be released. Make sure that in viewdidunload for custom cell class sets thumbnailImageView = nil.

Comment: I have done what you mentioned, including: making my imageview property as strong, and creating a viewDidUnload method for the custom cell class. The problem persists, so I will post the code from my custom cell class.

Comment: What is your way of knowing if it does not get released?

Comment: When I run it on my iPhone, I can see if I scroll down that images from other cells stay until the new one is loaded.

Comment: So lets assume you see 7 cells at a time without loading. In that case, you see images for cells 1-7 while the ones for 8-14 are being loaded. Once 8-14 loads then only 1-7 images disappear, is it the case?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24970/discussion-between-morkrom-and-nirav-bhatt)